# Use of custom projection change overlays behavior

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, map-projections

In the Google Maps example for custom projection in the documentation http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-projection-simple.html I noticed different marker behavior depending on the map type used.

- With Google map type : when the mouse is over a marker, the city is displayed,
- With custom projection map : when the mouse is over a marker, nothing is displayed.

As I used custom projection, I noticed that this anormal overlays behavior (polygons too) seems related with a problem with custom projection.

Do you confirm that it is a Google Maps API bug ? If yes, is there a workaround ?
Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The markers are there, there happens something when you hover them(the cursor changes and I see a tooltip with the city-name), but the sensitive area is not where you expect it(over the marker-image). Just search a little bit on the map, you'll find some sensitive area's.

So I would say it's a bug.

As a workaround you may use a custom overlay that contains custom markers.

Comment: I found anothe bug in the same context (using Chrome) : the mouse pointer disappear "under the map" after changing zoom.

Comment: stackoverflow is not the right place for bug-reports, you may report bugs here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list

Comment: Maybe you already know it since March : Google Maps support has moved to StackOverflow February 10th : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/MppSAw8qs5Y

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/forum  . SO is not the place for bug-reports